# JavaScript: Filter recipes based on recipe's ingredients and available ingredients at home

Tags: javascript

I want to filter recipes whose ingredients matches ingredients in the `availableIngredientsAtHome` array, while taking the `numberOfIngredientsRecipeCanMiss` variable in consideration.

In below scenario recipe1 and recipe2 should be included because recipe1 covers all ingredients. Recipe2 doesn't, but it is allowed to miss 1 ingredient. If `numberOfIngredientsRecipeCanMiss` is changed to 0, the result would only be recipe1.

Data structure can not change.

```
const recipes = [
    { 
        "title": "recipe1", 
        "ingredients": [ 
            { "ingredient_id": 1 },
            { "ingredient_id": 2 },
            { "ingredient_id": 3 },
        ]
    },
    { 
        "title": "recipe2", 
        "ingredients": [ 
            { "ingredient_id": 1 },
            { "ingredient_id": 2 },
            { "ingredient_id": 3 },
            { "ingredient_id": 4 },
        ]
    },
    { 
        "title": "recipe3", 
        "ingredients": [ 
            { "ingredient_id": 1 },
            { "ingredient_id": 2 },
            { "ingredient_id": 3 },
            { "ingredient_id": 4 },
            { "ingredient_id": 5 },
        ]
    },
]

const availableIngredientsAtHome = [
    { "ingredient_id": 1 },
    { "ingredient_id": 2 },
    { "ingredient_id": 3 },
]

const numberOfIngredientsRecipeCanMiss = 1

// Result here
```

Thanks!

Comment: You didn't try anything ?

Comment: @Peterrabbit I tried many things, but all were unsuccessful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can do this using Array `filter`. Inside the filter I'm converting each ingredient array into a `Set` of ingredient ids. Then I'm checking if every (`every`) `availableIngredientsAtHome` id is in the set and (`&&`) the tolerance `numberOfIngredientsRecipeCanMiss`

```js
const recipes = [    {         "title": "recipe1",         "ingredients": [             { "ingredient_id": 1 },            { "ingredient_id": 2 },            { "ingredient_id": 3 },        ]    },    {         "title": "recipe2",         "ingredients": [             { "ingredient_id": 1 },            { "ingredient_id": 2 },            { "ingredient_id": 3 },            { "ingredient_id": 4 },        ]    },    {         "title": "recipe3",         "ingredients": [             { "ingredient_id": 1 },{ "ingredient_id": 2 },            { "ingredient_id": 3 },            { "ingredient_id": 4 },            { "ingredient_id": 5 },        ]    },]

const availableIngredientsAtHome = [
    { "ingredient_id": 1 },
    { "ingredient_id": 2 },
    { "ingredient_id": 3 },
]

const numberOfIngredientsRecipeCanMiss = 1

const getFilteredRecipes = (recipes, numberOfIngredientsRecipeCanMiss) => {
  return recipes.filter(({ingredients}) => {
    const ingredientSet = new Set(ingredients.map(x => x.ingredient_id))
    const tolerance = ingredientSet.size-availableIngredientsAtHome.length <=  numberOfIngredientsRecipeCanMiss
    return availableIngredientsAtHome.every(x => ingredientSet.has(x.ingredient_id)) && tolerance
  })
}

console.log(getFilteredRecipes(recipes, 1))

console.log(getFilteredRecipes(recipes, 0))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```